# Iteration of arrays over a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

is there a simple method to iterate all Arrays which are in one Hashmap?

For example:

```java
 HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>
```

i search a element from a array which is in one of the HashValue.

Comment: What have you tried and what were the issues that you noticed? Generally speaking, if you find it tedious to iterate over the datastructures that you have, you might want to revisit your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an iterator to run through hashmaps.

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

for (List<String> values : map.values()) {
    for (String value : values) {
        // do what you want with the value here.
    }
}
```

To make this loop shorter take a look on LambdaJ.
Jakarta collections also has a lot of classes that may simplify this code. For example class that wraps several collections and exposes API of single collection. Something like `CollectionsCollection`. But unfortunately this library does not support generics yet.

Comment: thank you :) i thought there is a simple java-method...but's okay